# Child object identification issues by QTP on citrix

Tags: object, qtp, citrix, identification

We have our AUTs and QTP 11 installed on the same citrix machine. We are getting java object identification issues since some time. Can someone tell me if we need to change any environment variables to resolve this issue. If yes then which ones and how?
Or anything that can be done to resolve it.
QTP is not identifying the child objects of any window/dialog. Its identifying all objects as Window objects.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Just a clue - Launch the QTP first and then launch the AUTs.

Usually people used to launch the AUTs at first and try to SPY the objects where they face this kind of issues. So just have a double check on this point!

If this is not the case, we may think about other reasons. Just check and confirm.